# What is idiom suiting the statement "the office boy has more importance than the manager"

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

What is idiom, expression or proverb suiting the statement "the office boy/office peon has more importance than the manager, so you have to bend before them"

As in it is far more important to be in good books of the office boy/office peon than the manager or the authority. More often Managers or seniors in large or government organization have limited power and thus remain a figurehead or a mouthpiece.

It comes with connotation that since office boy/office peon in third world countries do lot of file forwarding from departments to departments they have know-how of the right connections to go to rather than going to the long bureaucratic process which does not promise the desired outcome too.

Answer (score 1):

**[the tail is wagging the dog](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/the-tail-is-wagging-the-dog)**

> phrase [VERB inflects]
>   If you say that the tail is wagging the dog, you mean that a small or unimportant part of something is becoming too important and is controlling the whole thing.

<sup>src: COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins Publishers</sup>